# What is the best way to get Similar article list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Rails application, where I can create lots of posts with tags. I know I can generate the lists of posts by using the tags but what I am thinking to get the similar posts list according to the title of the post. 
For example,

I have 3 posts like 
1. Hello Kathmandu, 
2. Hello World, 
3. Hello how are you

So, if I navigate to the Hello Kathmandu post, I am thinking of getting the above 3 posts as a similar posts since it has the Hello keyword common.

I am using elastic search in my app to handle the search request. And I tried to pass the page title to elastic search and get the response from there, but my app generated error.

I tried,

```
<%
    require 'net/http'
    uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/search.html?q=rails')
    req = Net::HTTP.get(uri) 
    %>
<%= req %>
```

I think this is the wrong method. I tried to find the related topic in Google too. 
Please share your ideas.

Comment: Elastic Search sounds like overkill for a relatively simple fulltext search. Why not go with something more simple like the [textacular gem](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) for Postgresql?

Comment: Does it supports MySql

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Vector Space Model, for matching the similarity between texts. It will help you rank those texts according to the closest match. for more information, check this link out.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model

I have also found this gem, which will be useful to integrate this into your Rails application.

https://github.com/jpmckinney/tf-idf-similarity

I have also found this presentation which will give you a clear idea of how it actually works! It is used by text search engines like Lucene/Solr.

http://www.slideshare.net/dalal404/document-similarity-with-vector-space-model

Hope this helps! :)